Web server is returning a unknown Error , Error code 520
Our website is hosted on Inmotion hosting and we are managing DNS on cloudflare.
we are continusely facing this error like 3 to 5 times a day. Some of our live user reported this user but after refresh it's disappear. some key points i am adding

We don't have too much users right now.
12GB RAM, VPS, 12 CPU
Laravel 8
we have cron jobs like 20 to 30.
PHP version we are using  ea-php74
max_execution_time : 120
memory_limit: 1024M
post_max_size : 768M
upload_max_filesize: 200M

i already applied queue jobs in laravel for sending email because our cron jobs mostly related to sending emails to Clients and freelancers
